# JavaMail - Stop automatically sending read receipts

Tags: java, email, exchange-server, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm developing a Mail Client (IMAP/SMTP) with `JavaMail`. This client talk to an Exchange 2010 Server that automatically sends read receipts when I set the flag SEEN in messages that require them. How can I avoid the server to send these receipts? I tried to remove the Disposition-Notification-To header from messages but i get the following exception:

```
javax.mail.IllegalWriteException: "IMAPMessage is read-only"
```

even if i open their folder in `READ_WRITE` mode. I read that this problem is due to an `IMAP` protocol limitation. Is there a way to not send read receipts?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in your client. Your client doesn't do it, and IMAP offers no way to configure Exchange.

(Also, IMAP offers no way to modify messages. Once stored, a message can be cached forever by any client and not be modified by any other client.)

Answer (score 0):

The right thing to do is to reconfigure the server.

Lacking that, you could make a copy of the message, modify the copy to remove the header, append the copy to the original folder, and delete the original.  You'll need to use the [IMAPMessage.setPeek](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPMessage.html#setPeek%28boolean%29) method to prevent the SEEN flag from being set on the original message.  Use the MimeMessage copy constructor to make the copy.  Note that this will be expensive if the message is large.

Comment: If I don't set the SEEN flag before deleting the original message the server sends a "Not read" notification.